# Chat quick* links should be always visible

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

I'm wondering what the motivation is to have the quickleave and quickswitch icons hidden by default and only visible when you hover over the area.

[image: icons]

With the icons hidden until you hover above them, this means that if you are moving your mouse there with the intent to switch rooms, it feels like you're clicking on nothing.

I felt this way in the previous iteration when the link was just text, but at least the link was several words wrong so that you just had to click in the general area.  With these small icons, you need to be much more precise.  Maybe it is just me, but I've clicked the quickleave icon several times by accident, and the empty space around the quickswitch icon many times when trying to switch to another room.

Is leaving a room such a common action that it is frequently done and needs to be immediately available like it is now?

(There's also a bug that duplicates these icons that this suggestion would fix.  Click room name, click x, click room name, click x, click room name, click x....  [Chat discussion here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/130136#130136))
[image: bug]

---

I suggest that the area be reverted back to its previous iteration without the quickleave link (as this, in my opinion, is something rarely done, is immediately available when in the room, and also available via the room's popup) and the quickswitch link being a text link.  Regardless of what the area contain, I propose it be **always visible**.

Comment: With the text links they were fairly... "conspicuous". Maybe with the icons this (always visible) is a good option.

Comment: +1 for always visible.  -0.49 for nixing the quickleave link.  I've used it, and it's not obtrusive.

Comment: @Popular, having the quickleave icon there just results in a smaller area I have to guess at to click on what I want.

Comment: @rchern, fair enough, but at the same time, it seems wrong to make me open up a room just to leave it.

Comment: @Popular, if you aren't in the room, you can click on the room name and there are action links in the popup.

Comment: @rchern, more clicking?  But that sounds like _work_!  I guess it's not so bad.  I actually didn't realize that those links were still there.

Comment: If both are really frequently used, then they should both be immediately accessible.  It is really just the guessing game arising from them not being always visible and being small icons that I'm questioning.

Comment: I actually think a better option would be to have clicking on a room be "switch to".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) a while ago.

Comment: Where is the award for the most gratuitous use of the new tag syntax in a serious screenplay?

Comment: @Gnome, just wanted to mark it with an accepted answer.  Edit it out if you feel inclined to. *shrugs*

Comment: I don't mean to pick on you (and that above is a reference to some popular fiction), it's just unreadable with black text and red background and I've seen so many people using that niche feature.

Comment: @Gnome, presumably the styling will get fixed.  I thought it already had been.

Answer (score 4):

Also, the icons suck. They're small, and accidentally clicking the wrong one produces annoying results. And why does the recycle icon switch rooms and the up-arrow leave a room? It's all so confusing...

"[leave]" and "[switch]" don't take up *that* much room, do they?